# How to convert a stream to enhanced loop

Tags: java, java-8

I have started working with Java 8 and trying to convert some stream to enhanced loop.

So, for the example, I'm trying to convert this stream to for loop. but, I'm not getting it right:

```
List<Job> jobs = shipment.getJobs();
Job shoppingJob = jobs.stream().filter(job -> job.isShopping()).findFirst().orElse(null);
Job deliveryJob = jobs.stream().filter(job -> job.isDelivery() || job.isRanger()).findFirst().orElse(null);
```

I want to know if it is possible to convert the above example to enhanced for loop. so far, I try to convert my for-loop code like this:

```
 List<Job> jobs = shipment.getJobs();
 Job shopping job = null;
 Job delivery job = null;
 Job rangerJob = null;
    if(jobs != null || jobs.isEmpty()) {
        for (Job job: jobs) {
            if (job.isShopping()) {
                shoppingJob = job;
            } else {
                if (job.isDelivery()) {
                    deliveryJob = job;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Note: the if-else construct is assuming that `job.isShopping()` and `job.isDelivery()` (or `isRanger()`) cannot be both `true` (same job) - it's reasonable, but is not what is implemented in the stream code (just a **note**)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point of `findFirst` is that the `Stream` pipeline will only evaluate elements of the `Stream` until it finds the first matching element (that passes your filter).

When you convert that to a for loop, you should break from the loop once you find a match. However, since you are transforming two `Stream` pipelines to a single for loop, you should only break from the loop after you find matches for both conditions.

```
List<Job> jobs = shipment.getJobs();
Job shoppingJob = null;
Job deliveryJob = null;
if (jobs != null) {
    for (Job job : jobs) {
        if (shoppingJob == null && job.isShopping()) { // this is the first shopping job
            shoppingJob = job;
            if (deliveryJob != null) { // we can break after finding a match for both conditions
                break;
            }
        }
        if (deliveryJob == null && (job.isDelivery() || job.isRanger())) { // this is the first delivery or range job
            deliveryJob = job;
            if (shoppingJob != null) { // we can break after finding a match for both conditions
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Technically, since the stream version of the code didn't null-check `jobs`, neither should the non-stream version.

Comment: What if 2 shopping jobs are found before the delivery job? Current code will return second shopping job, contrary to the `findFirst` of the stream version.

Comment: @Andreas yes, but since the OP's non-stream attempt did include a null check, I assumed it would be safer to keep it (the `jobs.isEmpty()` check, on the other hand, was both incorrect and unnecessary).

Comment: @Eran Thanks for your response, it worked. But actually, you don't have to `break` I think

Comment: @GustiBimoMarlawanto If you want the same output for the Stream and non-Stream versions, you must break (in case there are multiple elements of the Stream that satisfy either of the two filters/conditions)

Answer (score 2):

You should use `break` for `findFirst` function.

Below part is finding `shoppingJob` with breaking.

```
Job shoppingJob = null;
if (jobs != null || jobs.isEmpty()) {
    for (Job job : jobs) {
        if (job.isShopping()) {
            shoppingJob = job;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Below part is finding `deliveryJob` with breaking

```
Job deliveryJob = null;
if (jobs != null || jobs.isEmpty()) {
    for (Job job : jobs) {
        if (job.isShopping() || job.isRanger()) {
            deliveryJob = job;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

But you wants to find with one `foor loop` , you can also do like this;

```
if (jobs != null || jobs.isEmpty()) {
    for (Job job : jobs) {
        if (!shoppingJobFound && job.isShopping()) {
            shoppingJob = job;
            shoppingJobFound = true;
        }
        if (!deliveryJobFound && (job.isDelivery() || job.isRanger())) {
            deliveryJob = job;
            deliveryJobFound = true;
        }
        if (shoppingJobFound && deliveryJobFound) {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Technically, since the stream versions of the code didn't null-check `jobs`, neither should the non-stream versions.

Comment: yes, you are at right point. But in tried solution of questioner , i supposed he wants to check i think.

Answer (score 1):

I can see a couple of issues with the code you've posted. This is the code that should do what you're after

```
    if(jobs != null) {
        for (Job job : jobs) {
            if (shoppingJob == null && job.isShopping()) {
                shoppingJob = job;
            } 
            else if (deliveryJob == null && (job.isDelivery() || job.isRanger())) {
                deliveryJob = job;
            }
        }
    }
```

So the things that needed to change:

1). The second part of your very first if condition would throw a `NullPointerException` if the jobs list was `null`. You had

```
if(jobs != null || jobs.isEmpty()) {
```

Which translates to: if jobs isn't `null` go into the block, or if jobs is `null` call `isEmpty()` on `jobs` (and calling `isEmpty()` on `null` will throw a `NullPointerException`). The `isEmpty()` is also redundant, as you pointed out in comments.

Instead, I think this is all you need

```
    if(jobs != null) {
```

2). You need to make sure the variables `shoppingJob` and `deliveryJob` don't get overwritten once they've been assigned a value once, if you want to have something equivalent to `findFirst()` from the Stream code.

Otherwise if there's more than one shopping job or more than one delivery job in the list, those variables will actually end up assigned the last matching job in the list and not the first. This is why the first part of these conditions is necessary i.e. in this example, the `shoppingJob == null` bit

```
if (shoppingJob == null && job.isShopping()) {
```

3). There's no need to write an if nested inside an else clause, you can just use `else if` if you need a conditional else statement. Although in this case, to match the logic exactly, you shouldn't use `else` at all (in the original Streams code, if a job returned true for `isShopping` and `isDelivery`, the same job could be assigned to both variables, but if you use an else here that could only ever be assigned to one)

So instead of this

```
else {
          if (deliveryJob == null && (job.isDelivery() || job.isRanger())) {
```

You can just use an if statement (with no else)

```
if (deliveryJob == null && (job.isDelivery() || job.isRanger())) {
```

4). Lastly, in the original code, you are trying to replicate, `deliveryJob` was assigned to a job that returned true for either `isDelivery()` or `isRanger()`. In your for loop code, you were only checking `isDelivery()`

Hope that helps.

Comment: As others have pointed out on other answers, the original stream code posted doesn't include a null/empty check on the jobs list, but I've left it in here because there's an important logical error that I think should be highlighted regardless (if the poster did want to add that check in)

Comment: thanks for your help! yes, you're right, it will throw NPE if  I calling `isEmpty()` on `null`.  Actually, it doesn't need check if isEmpty() or it is `null` because `jobs` is `List`

Comment: good point, the isEmpty check is redundant given the way you are iterating. I'll update my answer

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Thanks

I just need to put `null` checking in each condition for `shoppingJob`and `deliveryJob`. It will be:

```
 List<Job> jobs = shipment.getJobs();
    Job shoppingJob = null;
    Job deliveryJob = null;
    Job rangerJob = null;
    for (Job job : jobs) {
        if (shoppingJob == null && job.isShopping()) {
            shoppingJob = job;
        }
        if (deliveryJob == null && (job.isDelivery())) {
            deliveryJob = job;
        }
    }
```